# Maping a set of numbers to a more limited one

Tags: functions

General: How to I construct functions in general that maps a certain set of numbers to more limited set is there a systematic way ?

Specific: For numbers from 0:63 I want to construct a mathematical function that maps 0 and 56 to 0, maps 7 and 63 to 1 and the rest of the numbers to any different number or numbers?

Comment: There are obvious ways to do this. Do you have a more general pattern in mind? The proposed problem is quite specific--if you can't solve that problem, you probably don't understand the question you are asking.

Comment: @MPW I mentioned one of the patterns in my question but I want to know if there is a general way to solve this type of problems ,my knowledge of mathematics is pretty much limited so if you don't mind elaborating on what you meant in case I didn't understand you well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about what you want better.  In your specific, we can define $$f(n)=\begin {cases} 0&x=0,56\\1&x=7,63\\2&\text{else} \end {cases}$$ but I suspect that is not what you are thinking.

Comment: yes I was thinking about a single equation using elementary or simple mathematical operations that achieves this function

Comment: This is a simple operation.  Following your comment on the other answer, this will be quite fast if implemented as if statements.  I could give you a big polynomial that you take the mod 56 of, but that would be much slower than this.  Why don't you (and others) like functions defined like this?

Comment: on certain machines and with certain algorithms the branching cost can be pretty much high compared to bitwise/arithmetic operations

Comment: Are you confusing a branch (which may send you somewhere else in the code) with a few if statements.  The above function must be fast compared to a 62nd degree polynomial evaluation, which has about 124 arithmetic computations.  In any case, neither is likely to be the slow part of your program.

Comment: the cost of conditional branching depends on the branch predictor and the pattern of the data the first isn't sophisticated in certain architecture and the second is highly unpredictable "random" , for the polynomial I may be able to optimize it using certain properties of primitive types and specific CPU instructions, as you said " neither is likely to be the slow part of your program" but I am asking this out of curiosity .

Comment: if you are interested read this :https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-the-cost-of-branch-misprediction and jalf's answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289405/effects-of-branch-prediction-on-performance

Answer (score 0):

It is called *identifying* and is represented by a function, in your chess case 
$\Bbb Z_{64}\to\Bbb Z_{64}$. Any function that isn't one-to-one define such identifications.

I guess that the numbers $0,\dots,63$ represent the chess board and that you want fastest possible identification method. In your specified case, $F(x)=(1 \operatorname{and} x)$ will work for the values $0,7,56,63$ but I don't know what you want for the other values ...

Comment: anything different

Comment: @johnathan: if the number $n$ is represented as 64-bit string $2^n$ it might be possible with fast masking.

Comment: yes n is 64 bit and by anding 2^n with bits corresponding with File A or B with Rank 1 or 8 I can get 2 values for it but I am asking if there is any  better/shorter way.

Comment: @johnathan: Then I think it can be proved impossible, if the question was more adequate formulated.

Comment: do you mind elaborating a little on this last comment

Comment: @johnathan: it just seems impossible to reduce the problem from 64 bits to 6 bits - it's a question of dependency.